# Getting back to a CSS position sticky element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a page where all sections fill the entire screen and are positioned with CSS `position: sticky;` in order to achieve a *layered* effect. See here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-khayyam-cgql1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

This all works great and as expected.

The problem comes however from navigating between these areas with JavaScript. If you try using the menu, you can see that the links will work on sections that we haven't fully gotten to yet (and therefore not "sticky") but does not allow you to "go back up" the page.

I believe this is an issue with `el.getBoundingClientRect()` once an element has become "sticky", its top value becomes essentially always zero.

Here I am using a small library called `Jump.js` to jump around but even in vanilla JS this issue would still be the same, as the problem is a result of the calculation from when the element becomes sticky.

Is there any way to find the original position for each section before it was sticky? At least that way I could navigate the user by setting the scroll position manually.

I am using Vue.js but that does not affect the issue at hand which is CSS and JS related.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <main id="app">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li @click="goTo('A')">Section A</li>
      <li @click="goTo('B')">Section B</li>
      <li @click="goTo('C')">Section C</li>
      <li @click="goTo('D')">Section D</li>
      <li @click="goTo('E')">Section E</li>
    </ul>
    <SectionItem id="A" color="red"/>
    <SectionItem id="B" color="green"/>
    <SectionItem id="C" color="blue"/>
    <SectionItem id="D" color="orange"/>
    <SectionItem id="E" color="purple"/>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import jump from "jump.js";
import SectionItem from "./components/SectionItem.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    SectionItem
  },
  methods: {
    goTo(id) {
      jump(`#${id}`, {
        duration: 300
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**SectionItem.vue**

```
<template>
  <div :id="id" class="SectionItem" :style="styles">
    <p>I am section item: {{ id }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SectionItem",
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    styles() {
      return {
        backgroundColor: this.color
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.SectionItem {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  border: 10px solid white;
}
</style>
```

I'm looking for any reasonable solutions that get get the auto-scrolling to work in both directions. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your `goTo` method should look:

```
goTo(id) {
  const el = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
  el.style.position = "static";
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    jump(`#${id}`, {
      duration: 300
    });
    el.style.removeProperty('position');
  });
}
```

See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-monad-e89ks).

Code should be self evident: set element's position to `static` using inline style, so the calculation is done correctly and remove the inline style position attribute in the next animation frame, so the element displays as set by the rest of the app (in this case, by CSS). Since it only happens for a single frame, it's not perceptible to human eye.

Note: I just wrote something quickly, to demonstrate the fix - it can probably be written more "vue like" (consider using refs).

Another note: if you're uncomfortable with toggling the element's position for a frame and you want to do it in a less aggressive way (towards the rendered elements) another approach is to clone the entire dom (without events), and do the same thing I'm suggesting, but on the clone. Once you have the value, you can delete the clone and pass it to the actual page. Obviously, the clone should have `position: absolute; width 100%; visibility: hidden; top: 0` and be a direct ancestor of `<body>`. Overall I believe it would be heavier (in terms of memory usage), but with regards to the actual page it would be less aggressive (it would avoid any side effects) - all layout, painting and rendering would be done correctly (as if you scrolled). By side effects I mean edge cases, such as triggers to any potential listeners to viewport intersection, affix plugins, scroll listeners, etc...

Comment: I tried your solution and it works a treat. Thank you very much. I see what you're saying about side-effects but my use-case is so simple that it shall suffice for now.

Comment: I think the short answer is, temporarily change CSS `position` to something `getBoundingClientRect()` can work with.

Comment: The `requestAnimationFrame` wrapper is for a more general case. In principle, you want to give Vue the chance to react to the change, before calculating the correct position (just in case it might have some computed props which result in different section heights - clearly not your case, at least not in what you've shown).

Answer (score 1):

JumpJS has an [option to pass in a number](https://github.com/callmecavs/jump.js/blob/2aa19ab339647261ddd02ec0628d85194c34bf6f/src/jump.js#L101) instead of a selector, so one way is to grab the initial section tops in `mounted()` and use them in `gotoId()`.

The `jump(number)` call expects a number relative to [location()](https://github.com/callmecavs/jump.js/blob/2aa19ab339647261ddd02ec0628d85194c34bf6f/src/jump.js#L28), which is `window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset`, so we have to change it to an absolute by passing the negative to the `offset` option.

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    SectionItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tops: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.tops = this.$children.reduce((acc, child) => {
      acc[child.id] = child.$el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      return acc;
    }, {})
  },
  methods: {
    goTo(id) {
      const offset = -(window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset); // make jump absolute
      jump(this.tops[id], { duration: 300, offset });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I will give this a go soon but already accepted an answer for now as it was the simplest thing to get the issue resolved. Thank you for this.

Comment: This will stop working correctly when page is resized or when sections change height. I initially wanted to go down this road and when I realized it's only working right once, I looked for a solution which would work with "current" heights, regardless of what they are.

Comment: Looking at the way [vue-sticky-directive](https://github.com/mehwww/vue-sticky-directive/blob/32b4c418b58c948ff38031afb02a3c107e21751f/src/sticky.js#L65) does it, a placeholder div is attached, which should make numeric jump possible by querying top position of the placeholder instead of the section.